# how do you iterate each item in array with every item in another array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

Hi I'm trying to iterate 1 array with another. For example for each item in list 1 replace it with each item in list 2.

```
list1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000];

list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];
```

printout:

```
1 chemistry 1997 2000
2 chemistry 1997 2000
...
physics 1 1997 2000
physics 2 1997 2000
...
physics chemistry 1 2000
physics chemistry 2 2000
```

How would I write something like this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a pattern in the printout...

Comment: Is that 3 elements from `list1` and one element from `list2`, in any order?

Comment: @AdamHughes -- It took me a while to figure it out, but there is a pattern (see my answer), and really... OP did an OK job of explaining it.  "for each item in list1, replace it with each item in list2".  the 'printout' could be formatted a bit better, but ...

Comment: This question probably would do a lot better if you showed us what you've tried to solve this problem up to this point.  1) it would make it more clear what you're trying to do, 2) it will help us to know what you're struggling with so that we can help you better.  I have an answer below (but I deleted it as I don't want to give an answer to a homework problem before I see you've made an effort yourself).  *hint*, think about what you need to do -- make a copy of the input list and then replace a field on it with a different value, repeat until no more replacements are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the items in `list2`, then the positions in `list1`:

```
for item in list2:
    for position in range(len(list1)):
        print(list1[:position] + [item] + list1[position + 1:])
```

Output:

```
[1, 'chemistry', 1997, 2000]
['physics', 1, 1997, 2000]
['physics', 'chemistry', 1, 2000]
...
['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 4]
[5, 'chemistry', 1997, 2000]
['physics', 5, 1997, 2000]
...
['physics', 7, 1997, 2000]
['physics', 'chemistry', 7, 2000]
['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 7]
```

Comment: Explanation for the downvote? I think this matches OP's expected results.

Comment: thanks marius but is there a way to stay on the same item in list 1 before moving on to the second item?

Comment: Yes, if you swap the for loops around, looping through position in the first loop, then item in the second

Comment: Great, but please lose the redundant parentheses in `list1[(position + 1):]` -- the only flaw that stops me from upvoting this otherwise excellent answer!-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli I usually use those parens when I'm slicing because I think it makes it clearer what's before and after the colon, i.e. for readability. Happy to drop them if you think it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I do think Tufte's principle -- "no wasted pixels!" -- applies to Python, as first emphasized (to the best of my knowledge) by J. Hallén.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need something like this here's the code:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
letters = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’]

for i in range(len(l)):
  for ch in letters:
    ll = l[0:i]
    ll.append(ch)
    ll += l[i+1:]
    print ll



**Output:**       
['a', 2, 3, 4, 5]
['b', 2, 3, 4, 5]
['c', 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 'a', 3, 4, 5]
[1, 'b', 3, 4, 5]
[1, 'c', 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 'a', 4, 5]
[1, 2, 'b', 4, 5]
[1, 2, 'c', 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 5]
[1, 2, 3, 'b', 5]
[1, 2, 3, 'c', 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'a']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'b']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'c']
```